# PayPal GetBalance in IPN Script

Tags: api, paypal, paypal-ipn

At the end of my PayPal IPN Script I'm trying to get my new balance with the GetBalance API.

Unfortunately sometimes the balance I receive is correct, sometimes it's the balance without the latest value.
I couldn't find any correlation neither with txn_type nor with payer_status or payment status.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks and best regards
Daniel

Comment: how frequent is sometimes? Are you seeing any pattern? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sometimes is like 50% are correct 50% are not. As I wrote I can't see any pattern at all. What I've tried is looking at about 50 IPN messages trying to find a pattern :D